# How do you access the Profiler API from pure managed C# code?

Tags: c#, profiler

**Background**

I am developing a library called [Harmony](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony) that currently uses detouring at the assembler level to monkey patch methods at runtime. This works fine and I got this to work on all combinations of hardware and .NET but it is sort of an ugly hack that does not work when methods are inlined.

**Scope**

I know roughly about the profiler API and that you can alter the IL before it reaches the JITer. My library already provides a high level way to get the modified IL body so all I need to do is to use the profiler API.

Asking around it was recommended to write small C/C++ modules accessing it but I rather would want to do this from my managed code. Reasons: my library should only be one final dll, I rather not want to deal with C/C++ code, different environments might make this hard.

**Question**

Is this approach possible? Is there an easier way? Is there a profiler library that hides this implementation and just gives me a high level replacement callback?

**Note**

Please do not question the motives of my library, I am fully aware that this falls outside of any “normal” C# programming. It’s mainly for patching and modding games and so far with 1500+ stars on GitHub a very successful project. I just want to lift it to an even more compatible level.

Comment: Can you do it from an `unsafe` code block?

Comment: In general, yes. I am already using some unsafe code in Harmony to write the assembler jump and to unprotect/protect the memory

Comment: The profiler API was explicitly not designed to be invoked from managed code and doing so is fraught with peril. Even unmanaged code can have a hard time using it properly, as it requires the occasional `__declspec(naked)` so as not to disturb any stack whatsoever. You can still have "one final DLL" if you write a C++/CLI assembly that incorporates the unmanaged bits and offers a managed wrapper, but even that has to tread very carefully to not cause endless headaches with JIT reentrancy. It's not necessarily easier than what you already have, if that works.

Comment: The main problem with the current approach is that if a method is inlined then writing a jump into the native code will not work because the jitter has already inlined that method at the places it’s normally called. 

With mono, I am successfully manipulating the method flags to mark it as no-inline but that seems not to work with all .NET versions.

Comment: Getting something that works with *all* .NET versions (including Core?) is incredibly tricky anyway, because even with the profiler API you're looking at some architecture-specific code. So hats off if you managed that in your current codebase. :-) What's more, I have no experience with Mono's internals, but does it even support the COM-based profiling APIs of Framework/Core? I know it has its own profiler functions, but that's a completely separate API. I'm skeptical they'd do all that work twice just to make your life easier... so you're looking at multiple codebases anyway.